# What happens to the $U(1)$ factor in the $U(N)$ SYM gauge group of the AdS/CFT correspondence?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I'm learning about the AdS/CFT correspondence. I know that from the open string perspective, the dynamics on a stack of $N$ coincident $D3$-branes is given by a $\mathcal{N} = 4$ Super Yang Mills theory with gauge group $U(N)$ in four spacetime dimensions.

However, as I understand it, the weak form of AdS/CFT relates $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM with gauge group $SU(N)$ to supergravity in ten dimensions on $AdS_5 \times S^5$.

I was confused since the gauge groups $U(N) \neq SU(N)$? How is this resolved then? Is this not a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111), section 3.1 page 58, there is a paragraph that answers your question:

> "A $U(N)$ gauge theory is essentially equivalent to a free $U(1)$ vector multiplet times
>   an $SU(N)$ gauge theory, up to some $Z_N$ identifications (which affect only global issues). In the dual string theory all modes interact with gravity, so there are no decoupled
>   modes. Therefore, the bulk $AdS$ theory is describing the $SU(N)$ part of the gauge
>   theory. In fact we were not precise when we said that there were two sets of excitations
>   at low energies, the excitations in the asymptotic flat space and the excitations in
>   the near horizon region. There are also some zero modes which live in the region
>   connecting the “throat” (the near horizon region) with the bulk, which correspond to
>   the $U(1)$ degrees of freedom mentioned above. The $U(1)$ vector supermultiplet includes
>   six scalars which are related to the center of mass motion of all the branes [151]. From
>   the $AdS$ point of view these zero modes live at the boundary, and it looks like we might
>   or might not decide to include them in the $AdS$ theory. Depending on this choice we
>   could have a correspondence to an $SU(N)$ or a $U(N)$ theory. The $U(1)$ center of mass
>   degree of freedom is related to the topological theory of $B$-fields on $AdS$ [152]; if one
>   imposes local boundary conditions for these $B$-fields at the boundary of $AdS$ one finds
>   a $U(1)$ gauge field living at the boundary [153], as is familiar in Chern-Simons theories
>   [25, 154]. These modes living at the boundary are sometimes called singletons (or
>   doubletons)"

As you can see it is up to you to include the $U(1)$ part in the $SYM$ side of the duality. This choice is related to the choice of including or not local boundary conditions to the $B$-field in the $AdS$ side of the duality. See also the reference inside this Review, like [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9812012.pdf)